# NodeJS Socket.io call from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am working on a node project where I need to use websockets. I got the basic implementation working for socket.io in my project. Here is the code for `server.js` so far

```
import app from '../app';    
import http from 'http';
import socket from 'socket.io';

    var server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(app.get("port"));
    server.on('error', onError);
    server.on('listening', onListening);

    const io = socket(server);
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log(`connected ${socket.id}`);
      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('disconnected');

      });
    });
```

Now if I need to call socket from another javascript file, how do I do that?
Something like this: From `a.js` I would like to call emit message from download function. The problem is that I don't have reference to `socket` object in `a.js`. It was defined in my `server.js` file. Any suggestions?

```
export const download = () => {
  //after file is downloaded, emit message using socket.io to user

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to inject the object into a function that you're calling. is a `Dependency Injection principle` in programming.
you can
a.js

```
export const download = (io) => { // io is the reference
    //do something with io like io.emit
}
```

then in your server you need to import the download function then pass the **io** in your code.

```
import {download} from "<src/file/of/a.ts>"
// somewhere in the code in server.js
download(io);
```

for ***Dependency Injection Principle*** reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection
and [What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)